# auto field value set in php

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

i am send some value ( name , email , contact number , etc ) from 
one url like http://www.abc.com/sendvalue.php 
to other url like http://www.otherurl.com/test.php 
and i want auto display name , email etc to this url (http://www.otherurl.com/test.php) form.

i have not access to target url source code . any idea using some javascript pass in url ...

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have access to the destination's source-code, you will not be able to implement this feature.

The only way you'd have would be some [**XSS** injection](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Cross-site_scripting) -- which actually means hacking that destination website *(finding a security hole, exploiting it ; and your hack will stop working when the security problem is fixed)*.